# How to write JDO query by using request.getParameter()?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am using google app engine for the first time. and new in web development. I read the documentation of google app engine but couldn't get one thing. I also googled but couldn't find something easy and simple. According to this query we will get all records with lastName Harold.

```
 Query query = pm.newQuery(Person.class, "lastName == 'Harold'"); 
 result = (List<Person>) query.execute();
```

In web application we take parameters by requests. How can i write the same query with only difference that in place of Harold we will use request parameter:

```
 request.getParameter("lastName");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do something like

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
query.setFilter("lastName = lastNameParam");
query.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");
...
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) query.Execute("Harold");
```

which is a very slight variation on the first example in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html